# Passing values through url for checkbox fields with same name to get ?tag=tag1+tag2+tag3

Tags: wordpress, forms, checkbox

I have Wordpress installed and I have this form on each category page sidebar:

`<form name="tags" onChange="document.forms.tags.submit();">
<input type="checkbox" name="tag" value="tag1" <?php if((isset($_GET["tag"])) && $_GET["tag"] == "tag1") { echo "checked";}?>>tag1<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="tag" value="tag2" <?php if((isset($_GET["tag"])) && $_GET["tag"] == "tag2") { echo "checked";}?>>tag2
</form>`

The goal is to create an url like /?tag=tag1+tag2 and so on.
With the above code I get the url like this: /?tag=tag1&tag=tag2.

I've searched for two weeks and tried a lot, but nothing works for me. I've tried for example

`<input type="checkbox" name="tag[]" value="tag1" <?php if((isset($_GET["tag"])) && $_GET["tag"] == "tag1") { echo "checked";}?>>tag1`

but then i get `?tag%5B%5D=tag1` and Wordpress don't find any results.

The form submit each time a checkbox is checked.

If I use radio input fields, then it works great, because then there's one value each time, but I want to pass multiple values with the same name and render a url like /?tag=tag1+tag2+tag3+tag4 etc.

Can anybody help me with this problem, because I don't know how to get this work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

this is what you want:

```
// This would output '/client/?s=word&foo=bar'
echo add_query_arg( 'foo', 'bar' );
```

take a look on [add_query_arg()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg) and [get_query_var()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var)

Consider on this example http://codepad.org/s08Jmseg

```
$url_string = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
// reuturn: tag=tag1+tag2+tag3

parse_str($url_string);

// $tag holds the value tag1+tag2+tag3
$string = urldecode( $tag );
$arr = explode(" ", $string);
$my_tag = "tag2";

if( in_array( $my_tag, $arr ) ) {
    // $key
    echo $my_tag . ' found!';
}
else {
    echo "Tag Not Found!";
}

//print_r($arr);
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this. I see I can change the url from ?tag=tag1 to ?example=tag1 but not how to change ?tag=tag1&tag=tag2 to ?tag=tag1+tag2. Can you give me some more information about how to handle this?

Comment: @edow this `+` is just a space the real value is tag1 tag2 that you can encode it with the use of urlencode(), take a look on this example https://ideone.com/Ka94a5

Comment: I see, but how do I let this work with a checkbox form? I want each input have the same name and give it the url /?tag=tag1+tag2

Comment: @edow i have updated the answer with example take a look and let me.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm a noob with this. I'm not sure what to do. Your code returns `tag2 found!` if `?tag=tag2`. I got the code working to return  `tag2 found!` and `tag3 found!` etc., but I don't know how to let this change my url to ?tag=tag1+tag2+... when I click a checkbox. I'll try something the following days, but if you or someone else can help me further I would appreciate it.